# Is a callback URL needed for the GoToWebinar integration?

Tags: extension, authentication

I am trying to upgrade the GoToWebinar extension which now uses OAuth2 authentication. With OAuth2 there is usually a callback URL used to provide the necessary auth token back to the caller. GoTo has a place for this.

However, it's not obvious to me with the Veda integration extension on this. Is anyone successfully using this extension currently?

Answer (score 2):

We've been successfully using it on our website for several years. Had some custom development done during the time the extension hadn't been updated in a while, but we're using the most recent iteration with no modifications and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Do you have a callback URL configured?  Where does it go?